# VMWARE ESXi5.0 update1 scp from vmkernel is slow

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, performance, host

My ESXi 5.0 update1 is a single server.
All my network environment are Giga-LAN equipments and NICs.

I want to backup all the files of every guest OS and ftp them to a NAS server.
My ESXi server's NIC is capable of running at 1000M bps speed and in VMware vSphere Client, it does show that that NIC is running at 1000M bps/sec.

My NAS server's NIC is also running at 1000M bps/sec.
However, I found that when I scp files from ESXi host to NAS (or from NAS to host) , the network speed is only 6MB/s.
I am sure that my NAS server's network speed is running at 1000bps/sec because when I ftp a big file from my Lenovo T400 to the NAS server through the same network router , the network showing on the NAS is about 60MB/sec.
And, when I ftp a big file from guest OS to the NAS server, the network speed showing on the NAS server is around 40MB/sec.

My problem is, how do I config my ESXi 5.0's network so that I can ftp files from ESXi 5.0 host to other machine(such as my NAS server) can reach the speed of at 40MB/sec at least.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

*WHY* are you trying to scp files this way, it's really not a particularly smart way of doing things, you know when you ssh/scp into the box you have to enable the 'remote support option' - well that's what it is, it's there for support - you *can* scp from it but it's a super-low priority thread and VMWare are looking to remove that interface entirely in future releases. Also if you're copying files directly there's no reason whatsoever to assume that they're in anything but a totally corrupt and non-quieced state.

If you're trying to just do VM backups there are lots of other methods out there, I don't use the free version but VMWare's VDR appliance works ok, there's other things like [ghetto-VCB](http://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-8760) as well that use APIs that are designed to do this and won't limit you.

Basically use the tools that are there instead of trying to hack your own way around.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation with ESXi. If you really *really* want to copy files yourself (see Chopper3's answer for suggestions of alternate solutions) and security is not a concern in your network, you could [enable FTP on your ESXi server](http://www.vm-help.com/esx/esx3i/ESXi_enable_FTP.php) which would allow for faster transfers. Keep in mind though that FTP

- transfers the data in the clear
- transfers the username/password combination in the clear

so if there is a chance of an adversary sniffing on your network, you should **definitely not be using this option**.